# iCarousel iOS 6 - Storyboarding

Tags: ios6, storyboard, sigabrt, icarousel

i tried to put iCarousel to my Storyboard project (my XCode is updated to iOS 6) exactly according to the StoryboardExample from Nick Lockwood.

But in the moment when I ctrt+drag UIView to connect dataSource, delegate and carousel with ViewController and let app run, the app don´t function and shows SIGABRT.

Has anybody idea what is wrong? Some settings...

Thank you for your help!

Iva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick already helped to somebody else to solve the problem - here:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/119

Replace initWithNibName:bundle: with

```
- (void)awakeFromNib

{
//the setup code from your initWithNibName:bundle: method
}
```

Thanks:)