# SIGABRT error in icarousel

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt, icarousel

I'm still having problems with icarousel, I now created a storyboard and copied the exact code that works.
However mine is giving the following error:

2013-01-14 23:56:00.755 testeiCarousel[2997:11303] Unknown class iCarousel in Interface Builder file.
2013-01-14 23:56:00.757 testeiCarousel[2997:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1595012 0x12a2e7e 0x161dfb1 0xd4f711 0xcd0ec8 0xcd09b7 0x23a573 0xcfb428 0x4070cc 0x12b6663 0x159045a 0x405bcf 0x2cae37 0x2cb418 0x2cb648 0x2cb882 0x21aa25 0x21adbf 0x21af55 0x223f67 0x1e7fcc 0x1e8fab 0x1fa315 0x1fb24b 0x1eccf8 0x25f7df9 0x25f7ad0 0x150abf5 0x150a962 0x153bbb6 0x153af44 0x153ae1b 0x1e87da 0x1ea65c 0x29fd 0x2925)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I searched informations, believe I'm doing something very wrong.
[iCarousel iOS 6 - Storyboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153617/icarousel-ios-6-storyboarding)
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/119

no resolved

my example with error [download](http://www.leandrodavi.com/testeicarousel.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was due to a wrong connection in the connection inspector